# Create a shader mix with a factor of Illuminated surfaces in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, shader-nodes

Is there a way to mix shaders with a factor that identifies illuminated or lighted surfaces?
For example: I have a space scene with earth planet in it, I want to cover the sun-lighted side with day texture and dark side with night texture.

- I made a shader with some workarounds: I created a plane with a Damped Track constraint that keep its face to the sun and projects UV on earth, so the factor to day and night of earth is always in the direction of the sun.
  But I'm looking for a more physical-real way to doing it... a factor that understands the way light brights the object and puts it to the shader.
  *In EEVEE there is a simple way: Toon BSDF -> Shader to RGB -> to Factor
  but Shader to RGB is not available in Cycles.

[image: The Earth with my Workaround Shader applied to:]

[image: My Workaround Shader]

Comment: In blender it's possible **to texture** lights. Experiment with it!